# How do I implement a button within a button in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, button

I have 2 use cases:

1. Closable button (clicking the X at the upper right corner will close the button)
2. Multi-action (possibly via combobox) button (e.g. Save, Save As)

Is this something that can be accomplished by templating the control? If so, please provide sample code or links that everybody can reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You design the `Content` of the `Button` with a `Grid` and a `Button` set it's margins as you would and name the button in the Content and use it's click event for your task. You will also have to handle the text you want to display with a `Label` or `TextBlock` since you are defining the Content explicitly. As you can see you can add anything you want inside the Content portion.

```
<Button ...>
  <Button.Content>
    <Grid ...>
      <Button .../>
      <TextBlock .../>
    </Grid>
  </Button.Content>
<Button>
```